# SQL WHERE With Nullable Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query that I need to return rows based on the following possibilities:

```
ReqType
------
NULL
LTL
TL
```

To get a better idea of what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable MT
WHERE MT.ReqType = @param1
```

The parameter that is being passed is @`param`. Possibilities for @param can be NULL, TL or LTL.

@`param` and `ReqType` are `nvarchar(3)`

Comment: `MT.ReqType = @param1 or (MT.ReqType is null and @param1 is null)`

Comment: when you say @param1 can be NULL do you mean SQL NULL type?

Comment: @DaniDev Yes I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` doesn't work with `=`, so you need more explicit logic:

```
WHERE (MT.ReqType = @param1 OR
       (MT.ReqType IS NULL AND @param1 IS NULL)
      )
```

Comment: Wow thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for saving me time!

Answer (score 2):

If `@param1` (can be) `SQL` `NULL` then you could also do:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable MT
WHERE isnull(MT.ReqType, '')  =  isnull(@param1,'')
```

*That would not work if you are allowing empty string for your MT.ReqType. In that case you could pick another char to replace null values with.

Answer (score 1):

Works the same as Gordon's, a little more compact, note the use of coalesce. I don't think this is Index friendly so you might want to be careful how you use it.

```
declare @test table 
( 
    ReqFld1 varchar(4),
    ReqType varchar(3)
)

insert into @test values ('FLD1', 'LTL')
insert into @test values ('FLD2', 'TL')
insert into @test values ('FLD3', NULL)

declare @srch varchar(3)

select @srch = null
select * from   @test 
where  coalesce(ReqType, '') = (coalesce(@srch, ''))

select @srch = 'LTL'
select * from   @test 
where  coalesce(ReqType, '') = (coalesce(@srch, ''))

select @srch = 'TL'
select * from   @test 
where  coalesce(ReqType, '') = (coalesce(@srch, ''))
```